# Error: The required parameter 'sequence' is empty. Rerun the command with --sequence flag

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

i am working on hyperledger 2.2 and ubuntu 20 system.
I tried to approve the installed chaincode by using command

bash# export CC_NAME=basic

bash# export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel

bash# peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --name $CC_NAME --version 1 --package-id $PACKAGE_ID --sequence 1 --init-required --signature-policy "OR ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer','Org3MSP.peer')"

[image]

can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you done an " export PACKAGE_ID= " with the ID the "peer lifecycle install" returns?? I had the same error and it was a mistake in the environment variable PACKAGE_ID

Answer (score 0):

problem is Package ID as answered above. you have to export it. Or you can run 'query installed' command and chaincode approveformyorg command together and store Packcage ID in a txt file. Ie peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled>&log.txt